# How can I take off a letter from a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to know how can I take a character out of a string?

I have a date:

```
$date = "04.08.2013";
```

I would like to take just the first 2 zeros off. Like that:

```
$date = "4.8.2013"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $date); $date = $date->format('j.n.Y');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) to separate the string into an array then use [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ltrim.php) to delete "0"

i.e.

```
$date = explode(".", "04.08.2013");
$new_date = implode(".", array(ltrim($date[0],"0"), ltrim($date[1],"0"), $date[2]));
```

or something like that

Answer (score 2):

A simplish (read: hacky) solution would be:

```
$date = implode('.', array_map(function($x) { return (int)$x; }, explode('.', $date)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can may also get it done quickly using a regex:

```
$new_date = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\.)0/', '', $date);
```

Or more simply without the lookbehind (thanks @IlmariKaronen):

```
$new_date = preg_replace('/\b0/', '', $date);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JK38Ph)

Comment: Alternatively, `preg_replace('/(^|\.)0/', '$1', $date)` or even `preg_replace('/\b0/', '', $date)` avoids the need for look-behind.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I always forget about the back-references, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Also, if you need to remove more than one leading zero, just stick a `+` after the `0`. You could even use `preg_replace('/\b0+\B/', '', $date)` to strip all leading zeros from all numbers, except for the last zero in `0000`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen correct, I just commented that because I also tend to convert to number when removing leading `0`'s, but that's easy to fix regex-wise too as you've said so I'll remove that part. Thanks again. `:P`